# How to check if real has any digits after floating point

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting, type-conversion

I got a table with multiple real numbers. It looks like this:

| ParticipantId | GWF_Score |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 185 |
| 456 | 193,5 |
| 789 | 80 |

I've build a stored procedure which returns me this table in XML.

I have to print the score like its written in the table.

If I write it like this
`convert(decimal, GWF_Score) as [@points],`
I'll get 185,194,80

If I write it like this
`cast(GWF_Score as decimal(10,2)) as [@points],`
I'll get 185.00, 193.50, 80.00

If I write it like this
`(case when GWF_Score % 1 != 0 then cast(GWF_Score as decimal(10,2)) else convert(decimal, GWF_Score)end) as [@points],`
I'll get an error that says that real and int are not compatible with the modulo-operator.

Comment: I would recommend doing this in your presentation layer instead of in the database.  The database is meant for holding data.  Your presentation layer is meant for formatting.

Comment: This looks like a job for your presentation layer, *not* the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
(case when GWF_Score % 1.0 != 0.0 then cast(GWF_Score as decimal(10,2)) else convert(decimal, GWF_Punkte)end) as [@points]
```

Comment: "The data types real and numeric are incompatible in the modulo operator."